# How to restore the default short-cut key binding?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

[image]

How to restore the default shortcut key binding?
I messed it up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer, just install dconf-editor, open it and search media-keys

Comment: Settings for media-keys are found in:
gnome>settings-daemon>plugins>media-keys